# Lilypad upload error

Tags: lilypad, ftdi, programmer, avrdude

I'm trying to get the Lilypad working on my machine but i get the following error.

I had a Google for it but everything keeps pointing to a problem with the board. I swapped it out and tried another Lilypad but got the same error...

the one i am using is the first [Lilypad with the FTDI connection](http://web.media.mit.edu/~leah/LilyPad/01_computer_attach.html).

This is the error message i am getting:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're not selecting the correct board within the Arduino IDE.
Be sure to:

1) Download the latest version of Arduino from http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software
2) Install the Arduino IDE and FTDI drivers
3) Select Tools>Board>LilyPad Arduino W/ATMega328

Cheers,

Marcus